# Why listFiles() behaves differently in different platform?

Tags: java, linux, windows, amazon-web-services

Inside a folder I have three files A.txt,B.txt,C.txt. I am executing the below mentioned program.

```
    for(File a: path.listFiles()){
                System.out.println("List files"+a);
}
```

If am running the above program in windows machine I am getting the output A.txt, B.txt and C.txt. If I am running the same program in AWS EC2 Linux instance am getting the output A.txt,C.tct and B.txt. Why the same program is behaving differently in different platforms ?

Comment: `listFiles()` calls a native function that lists all files inside a folder/directory. Depending on the filesystem and drive that function may return an unordered list of files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `listFiles` method does not guarantee any order. Different filesystems and OS can give different sortings.

But what `listFiles` does, however, return an array, sortable with `Arrays.sort()` that works because `File` is comparable class, which by default sorts pathnames lexicographically.

```
File[] files = path.listFiles();
Arrays.sort(files);
for(File a : files) {
    // same exit for all platforms...
}
```